# Filter list's elements by type of each element

Tags: python

I have list with different types of data (string, int, etc.). I need to create a new list with, for example, only int elements, and another list with only string elements. How to do it?

Comment: use `for` loop and `isinstance(element, int)`, etc.

Comment: And you might want to try the `filter` method, or list comprehension

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [list  comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
integers = [elm for elm in data if isinstance(elm, int)]
```

Where `data` is the data. What the above does is create a new list, populate it with elements of `data` (`elm`) that meet the condition after the `if`, which is checking if element is instance of an `int`. You can also use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter):

```
integers = list(filter(lambda elm: isinstance(elm, int), data))
```

The above will filter out elements based on the passed lambda, which filters out all non-integers. You can then apply it to the strings too, using `isinstance(elm, str)` to check if instance of string.

Comment: @IlyaSpark No problem, glad to help

Comment: isinstance(True, int) -> True

Comment: @EgorOsaulenko Yes, booleans in Python are really integers in disguise. True is 1, False is 0.

Comment: integers = [elm for elm in data if isinstance(elm, int) and not isinstance(elm, bool)]

Comment: Not so long developing with python myself (came from c#) and this one was a surprise. I mean - yes, during the implementation of bool it looked suitable, but nowadays..

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list by type, and then use `groupby` to group it:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = ['a', 1, 2, 'b', 'e', 9.2, 'l']
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: str(type(x)))
>>> lists = [list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: str(type(x)))]
>>> lists
[[9.2], [1, 2], ['a', 'b', 'e', 'l']]
```

Comment: The OP seems to want separate lists without sublists, but great answer nonetheless!

Comment: @AndrewL. - They are still separate. They just don't have handcrafted labels. However, that could easily be accomplished with a dictionary instead, e.g. `lists = {k:list(v) for k,v in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: str(type(x)))}`. The benefit is, of course, that the names are generated automatically and can be easily organized.